# WordPress Polylang not showing lang icon

Tags: wordpress, polylang

WordPress with Polylang is not working properly. For some reason some of the menus and submenus are showing **LANGUAGE** instead of language flag image. Beside when you click to language of the non working menu items it redirects to **#pll_switcher**

Any help highly appreciated. [image: Preview]

In editing mode looks OK
[image: Editing mode]

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to Polylang support? Without code, we would only be guessing and since this is related to a plugin, I would suggest the support team first.

Comment: No subscription for professional support sorry... :( Any other options I could try to debug?

Comment: If you're using a custom theme, switch to a WP theme like 2019. Disable all plugins except for PolyLang. If the problem goes away, reactivate all plugins one by one until you find one that breaks it. If the problem goes away using a WP theme, you know it's your theme.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did tried, disabling theme and setting different theme. Same thing. I did disable the very few pulgins... no change. Funny in preview mode during editing works OK thou. P.S. Just edited the post and added editing mode preview for clarity.

Comment: I see you're using Divi. Divi and Polylang may have issues. Not sure though. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution disinfor.

Comment: Ok, I figured out what was going on. It was a plugin issue WP Fast Cache not compatible with Polylang. Never figured out how I missed that one disabling it and testing... Thanks again disinfor.